# HDD SMD component with 12 pins, 6 on either side - is it a connector?

Tags: identification

(I apologize if this Stack community is inappropriate for this question. Feel free to move it.)

I have a 2TB My Passport Pro external hard drive. A couple of days ago, the drive malfunctioned and smoke starting coming out from the USB 3.0 connector. I opened up the drive and there's this rectangular connector-looking component next to the USB connector:

[image: Back of the PCB]

[image: Component from above]

Could anybody help me identify what this is?

Comment: What for? There doesn't seem to be any evidence that this is where the smoke came from ...

Comment: That does look like a connector. Unused even, since it has the Kapton tape still attached to it, that is used to allow pick and place machines to attach to it.

Comment: It's a SMD connector. There's [similar drives](https://www.datarecoverydublin.ie/res/DR_-_RSADA_-_External_Hard_Disk_Recovery-proofed-01Mar_html_m7d4e28ca.jpg) with a trough hole connector in that position.

Comment: @brhans that's true, the smoke came from the micro usb connector (which is indeed a bit melted on the inside). I was hoping I could use that connector as a different means of transferring data from the drive, but I think that connector is there for programming the drive logic or something...